# How to increase the carrier signal voltage of RF AM modulation?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, signal, modulation, ham-radio

The circuit below is an example for RF modulation.
[image]

Question is about carrier signal voltage of rf AM modulation.
What does happen when the message signal will be amplified and it would have more voltage and current than the carrier wave. For example, message signal is stronger and has more power than the carrier signal. All I know is that the message signal will be transmitted very weak for close distance.
How can I amplify the carrier signal?
Which type of amplifier can be useful? Class A,B,C..

[image: wave]

It would be helpful, when an example can be demonstrated by a picture.

Here are useful parameters, I use at workplace:
For AM modulation:

Tank circuit: 30pF 0.3uH ~50MHz
Bypass capacitor: 4.7pF
Resistor: 1k
Transistor: 2N2222

Comment: turn the schematic diagram 90 degrees counter-clockwise so that it conforms to convention ... Vcc at top, gnd at bottom

Comment: Yes, you are right. I apology for the picture. I hope you can make an exception for the convention.

Comment: @lastime you have every right to ignore the schematic orientation convention. We have every right to ignore the question, and go on to something easier to read. noitnevnoc thgir ot tfel eht erongi dluoc I, the meaning is still decipherable, just harder to read.

Comment: That is a very bad depiction of an AM waveform iin the last image. It seems to be modulating both amplitude and frequency in sync!

Comment: Why should this circuit oscillate at all?